# is there any tool available for getting xpath intelligently

Tags: javascript, xpath

i have created a basic JS function which will return xpath on clicking any HTML element. But it gives the basic xpath-for example like this-
//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1].

Now my question is, is there any intelligent way to get best xpath-like taking descendants, siblings and all. not always from id and position like the way above. i want to use it for testing applications so that manual writing of xpath is omitted and extra work is saved.

Comment: Maybe you need to define what you mean by *`intelligently`*

Answer (score 1):

**There is no Intelligent xpath. Only good ones (and bad ones which deliver nothing !)**

**The most important thing is that: xpath is not unique to select an element.**

In your XML, the xpath given is the more precise

```
//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]
```

If we make some assumptions, we could guess that [1] means unique, so we get:

```
//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a
```

It is only a guess (certainly false).

So, what you keep is:

- the path of tags: div, div, div, ul, li, a
- some parameter: id
- some index: 3, 2

If you know that there are only one < a > tag in a tag with id=main,

you could do:

```
//*[@id='main']//a
```

**Conclusion: only if you know the good (stable) structure of you main, you can yourself create smart xpath**

If not, you could try to do some tricks like me, but it is unpredictable in most cases, and then unreliable.

So difficult to do it *automatically*.